# Erro ao criar JOB no Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle

Quando vou criar uma job no oracle está aparecendo este erro.

> ORA-01882: timezone region %s not found.

Como resolver este problema?

Comment: Como é o comando para criar o job !?

Comment: @Andre, poderia [edit] sua resposta e adicionar o script de criação da JOB? Pode ser que o erro esteja no `next_date`, mas precisamos saber da sua necessidade para te ajudar.